# What's the cost of rebalancing when you buy through a fund supermarket?

Tags: united-kingdom, portfolio, rebalancing

I was reading about how to rebalance a funds portfolio and the main drawback seemed to be that you could incurred in more costs than you would if you just do it sporadically.

I understand this problem if you buy directly through the fund manager or a broker that doesn't rebate the initial commission but I was wondering if there's any cost at all if you sell a fund and then reinvest that amount to rebalance your portfolio via a fund supermarket that rebates 100% of the initial commission?

I've not seen any article talking about this route...

Comment: Not sure if I'm mistaking something but what I was understanding is that you can open a fund supermarket account and there's no need for any other brokerage account. You would be able to buy/sell funds from within the fund supermarket account free (as they would rebate 100% of the initial cost).

Comment: If you buy no-load funds, the point is rendered moot so long as you don't trade more often than they permit. Some hav a rule, no selling for X days, can be 30,60, etc. normal rebalancing should not be impacted by this.

Comment: @Dilip, I'm from the UK, so not sure if things are different here but I think they're offering you exactly the same shares but with an initial discount (e.g. http://www.hl.co.uk/funds/popular-investments/investec). 

My question was trying to understand if there's any other charge when you try to rebalance, as all the articles I've read about the subject doesn't comment on these fund supermarkets.

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer, I didn't know they could have that condition. Do you know if you incur any dealing cost when you trade under their conditions? or is it totally free in this case to sell existing funds and reinvest in others to rebalance?

Comment: They 'could,' but you need to check the rules for each fund you might wish to trade. You can understand why, as a fund manager, you prefer long term investors, not those who are timing the market on tiny swings. If that's what one wishes, they should use ETFs instead.

Comment: I have added the united-kingdom tag to the question, and am deleting my previous comments since they are likely to be irrelevant to the issues being raised.

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer, I see, thank you! I'll swee how ETFs work as well.

Comment: @Dilip, sorry for the missing information, I just realized when I read your comments. Many thanks for adding the tag.